# How do i hide and toggle popover element when i click on the same div or outside of the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to toggle popover element if it is clicked outside of the div element containing the popover and if clicked on any other div containing popover. 
        I went through other post that did not help or I could not figure out how do I implement in my scenario.

My html

```html
<div id="myTableDiv">
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>Product</td>
      <td>Qty</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="popUpClass" rel="popover" data-content="" data-reason="returnded reason is factory damage">
          <span style="margin-right:5px">shirt</span>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="font-size:12px; color:red"></i>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="popUpClass" rel="popover" data-content="" data-reason="returnded reason is size mis match">
          <span style="margin-right:5px">shoes</span>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="font-size:12px; color:red"></i>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

```js
$('#myTableDiv').on('click', '.popUpClass', function(e) {
  $(this).popover({
    content: $(this).data('reason'),
    container: 'body'
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello as the documentarion says [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#dismiss-on-next-click) you should add a tabindex attribute so your `<div>` will be:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="popUpClass" rel="popover" data-content="" data-reason="returnded reason is factory damage">
      <span style="margin-right:5px">shirt</span>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="font-size:12px; color:red"></i>
</div>
```

And in the configuration of your popover you have to add the trigger:

```
 trigger: 'focus'
```

I hide all the popovers and then show only the clicked element

Finally your code could be:

```
$('#myTableDiv').on('click', '.popUpClass', function(e) {
  $(this).popover({
    trigger: 'focus',
    content: $(this).data('reason'),
    container: 'body'
  })
$('.popUpClass').popover('hide');
$(this).popover('toggle');
})
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/checosele/u03wdep2/16/) you can find the complete example

Comment: It works fine when popover is opened first time.
After opening up other popover cells and revisit back to the previous, it looks like as if glitched out. 
opensup and close and click again opens up. So it takes two clicks. to open up.

Comment: If you change this $(this).popover('toggle'); for $(this).popover('show');?

Comment: if I did so, it just open and close on second visit.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? Could you add a fiddle example or something like that?

Comment: I think I did it with your help. Thank you. What I did is I added data-dismiss attribute and then  commented out .popover('hide'); but kept toggle.